# Knockout not binding submit with JQuery1.10.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, unobtrusive-validation

EDIT:
this is actually Knockout, JQuery 1.10.2 and trying to override the  jquery.unobtrusivevalidation ErrorPlacement function... stopping the submit binding work on a form element.

If I run the same code with JQuery 1.8.2 then just change my JQuery file to 1.10.2 my submit function stops firing... has anyone seen similar to this?

i'm going to post as much relevant code as I can in case its something unexpected but the main point is that submitForm bound to the form submit event perfectly well with jquery 1.8.2 and without any other changes jquery 1.10.2 doesn't touch submitForm (testing with break points and alert() statements).
All other knockout bindings still seem to work.

please help. thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/Content/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/Scripts/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/Scripts/knockout-helpers.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/Scripts/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/Scripts/date.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/Scripts/global.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/Scripts/jquery.dirtyform.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/Scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/Scripts/sessionTimer.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/Scripts/jquery.livequery.js"></script>



<script src="/Content/Scripts/Ecdm/myCode.js"></script>




</head>


<form action="/Apply" data-bind="submit: submitForm" id="myApplicationForm"         method="post">

<!-- html form stuff -->

</form>
<script>

    var view; 

        $(function() {


        view = new ModelView({
                formSelector: '#myForm',
    });

  // Base JS model
        var model =
            {                
                someProperty: '@Model.SomeProperty',
};


view.bind(model);


});


</script>

</html>
```

myCode.js:

```
function ModelView(params) {

    var self = this;

  // Default parameters
    var args = $.extend({
    formSelector: 'form'    }, params);

   this.bind = function (model) {
  // Apply KO bindings
    ko.applyBindings(self);
    };


    this.submitForm = function () {
    var form = $(args.formSelector);
    form.validate();
    if (form.valid()) {
        var referenceNumber = $('#ReferenceNumber');

        if (a==b) {

            showConfirmation();

            return false;
        }

        g_showWait("Please wait...");
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: A typical task for [binary search debugging](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/181223/40625), I'm afraid...

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Jeroen. that was all I could do with no error messages. I managed to track it down to overriding the jquery unobtrusive validation like in this [blog](http://www.wiliam.com.au/wiliam-blog/sydney-web-design-overriding-mvc-unobtrusive-client-validation-error-placement) ... I've tried knockout binding after and before the override.  I can change other settings such as errorContainer, errorElement ... but if I touch errorPlacement the binding just doesn't work... any other suggestions at all?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the validate declaration notation rather than directly setting the validator settings but I don't know why.  If anyone could explain I would be grateful (i'm sick of looking at it:))
errorPlacement was successfully overridden and working in both cases.  submit knockout binding just didn't work.

Instead of overriding the errorPlacement function like this

```
$("form").each(function() {        
        var validator = $(this).data('validator');
        if (typeof validator != 'undefined') {
            validator.settings.errorPlacement = $.proxy(function(error, inputElement) {
                //
                // do stuff with the error object
                //
             }, $(this));
         }
 });
```

I changed it to this just try anything and it worked:

```
$("form").each(function () {
    var validator = $(this).data('validator');
    if (typeof validator != 'undefined') {
        $(this).validate({
            errorPlacement: $.proxy(function (error, inputElement) {
                //
                // do stuff with the error object
                //
             }, $(this));
         }
 });
```